# PHP Echo to a href - ' and "

Tags: php, cpu-word, href

I have a hint echo'd however, i have a issue with " and '  i can echo numerical values to the string, but not words..

```
$hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
 onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.musicDetailTitle4.value=5;
 document.contactForm.musicDetailArtist4.value=foo;">fill form</a>'.
```

5 works but foo doesn't works.

**UPDATE**

Still not getting an output

```
$hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value=\"$artist\"; document.contactForm.itemDetailArtist4.value=4;">fill form</a>'.
```

**Whole Code**

```
echo $hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value="'.$brand.'"; document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value=4;">fill form</a>'.$artist."-".$title."-".$id."</a>";
```

*Output is...*

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value=" ";="" document.contactform.itemDetailTitle4.value="4;&quot;">fill form</a>Tomato Soup-Heinz-0001<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value=" ";="" document.contactform.itemDetailTitle4.value="4;&quot;">fill form</a>Tomato Soup-Heinz-0001
```

Comment: You could try and do `\'foo\'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes

```
$hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.musicDetailTitle4.value=5; document.contactForm.musicDetailArtist4.value=\'foo\';">fill form</a>'.
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have much to do with PHP but rather JavaScript.

When passing a numeric value you just pass the number itself, but when passing strings you must wrap them in quotations otherwise the compiler will mistake "foo" for a variable named `foo` which may or may not exist.

As others mentioned, all you have to do is wrap your string like so:
`\'foo\'`

The slashes are because you don't want to close your `echo` which was also opened using a single quote, so you need to escape the character so when it's echoed to the user it will become `'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.musicDetailTitle4.value=5; document.contactForm.musicDetailArtist4.value=\'foo\';">fill form</a>'.
```

When declaring a **string** value you must add quotes, and when adding it in this way you must escape those quotes using the `\` key.